# Netty 4: writeAndFlush ByteBuf and reference count

Tags: netty

As it is said in the [doc](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/New-and-noteworthy-in-4.0):

> When an outbound (a.k.a. downstream) message reaches at the beginning
>   of the pipeline, Netty will release it after writing it out.

So in normal case, the reference count of `ByteBuf` will be decreased after [writeAndFlush](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundInvoker.html#writeAndFlush-java.lang.Object-io.netty.channel.ChannelPromise-) is called successfully.

**What about error occurs?**

Suppose I have two channels : `firstChannel` & `secondChannel`. If the `ByteBuf` is failed to sent to the `firstChannel` then it need be sent to the `secondChannel`

Code example is below.

```
final ChannelFuture future = firstChannel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf.asReadOnly()).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
        // Is the reference count decreased already before entering this method?
        if (!future.isSuccess()) {

            byteBuf.retain(); 
            secondChannel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
        }
    }
});
```

**Will the reference count be decreased even if error occurs?**
**Is the reference count decreased already before `operationComplete` is fired?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even on failure it will release the buffer so your code will not work. You would need to `retain()` the buffer to ensure the increment count is 1 when the listener is called and then decrement it by your self if the future was successful.

Something like this:

```
final ChannelFuture future = firstChannel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf.retain().duplicate()).addListener(new     ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
        if (!future.isSuccess()) {
            secondChannel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
        } else {
            byteBuf.release();
        }
    }
});
```

Also note that I call `duplicate()` as well to ensure we not modify the reader/writer index of the buffer that may be passed to the second channel later on.

Comment: I am using `asReadOnly()`, is it the same as `duplicate()` in this case?

Comment: @NormanMaurer, so, writeAndFlush will ALWAYS release the buffer? No matter what happens, a call to writeAndFlush will always release the buffer? Or does it have any catch or any scenario in which writeAndFlush will not release the buffer?

Comment: it always release the buffer as long as the "write / flush" is not dropped by any of your ChannelOutboundHandler implementations. In this case the handler is responsible to release it.